# Why does isArray not work with brackets in other method?

Tags: javascript

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  const flat = [].concat(...arr);
  return flat.some(Array.isArray) ? steamrollArray(flat) : flat;
}
```

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  const flat = [].concat(...arr);
  return flat.some(Array.isArray()) ? steamrollArray(flat) : flat;
}
```

Why does isArray not work with brackets and in which cases are no brackets required for methods?

Comment: with brackets you need something like `flat.some(x => Array.isArray(x))`. this is what is shortened as `flat.some(Array.isArray)`

Comment: @cmgchess Well, it just happens to work since `Array.isArray` only takes 1 parameter. Technically, it would be the same as `(x, index, array) => Array.isArray(x, index, array)`.

Comment: Without brackets you are passing it as callback to be called by some to do the check. With brackets you are calling isArray which returns false immediately and so you are passing false to some

Comment: @pink yeah forgot to mention that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `isArray` and everything to do with the difference between a *function reference* and *calling a function*.

Look closely at what this code does:

```
flat.some(Array.isArray)
```

This passes a *function reference* to [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).  That function will be invoked on every member of the `flat` array and the results of having invoked that function will be used by `.some()` to return its result.

Compare that with what *this* code does:

```
flat.some(Array.isArray())
```

This *calls* `Array.isArray()` *immediately* and passes its *result* (which is simply `false` because no array was provided) to `.some()`.  That result will then *fail* to be called on any member of the `flat` array, because `false` is not a callable function.

> in which cases are no brackets required for methods?

It all depends in whether you want to invoke the function *right now* or pass the function along to something else to invoke it *later*.  Parentheses are used to invoke the function.